# stacked barplots of the same height

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2

I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
col1  col2   col3   col4     cr
84  88.242  9.833   4.194     A
94  107.571 10.917  3.708     B
188 240.288 16.917  6.333     A
245 371.005 22.333  10.389    A
114 131.599 9.167   4.25      A
71  100.751 8.167   3         B
118 138.543 11.167  4.278     A
162 203.435 14.667  6.444     B
123 152.032 12.167  4.639     B
115 126.945 11.667  5.056     A
125 134.178 10      4.639     B
119 138.926 9.5     4.222     A
106 129.19  9.833   3.833     A
146 162.319 9.833   4.118     A
```

I've tried plotting the data using simple `barplot` command but its not giving the graph I actually want. I am looking to generate a plot of lets say 10 bars for each column (each bar would represent a range, for example 0-20, 20-40 and so on), having the `X` axis as the `column values`, the `Y` axis as `% frequency` (of `A` and `B`). `A and B stacked` in different colors (please note that the height of the bars has to be the same, since the Y axis is the % frequency).

This is what I am looking to generate

[image: google_image_stacked_barplot]

1 bar per column... any idea what command i should use for this.

(please ignore the axes names in the photo, it is just a photo i found on google, representing what i need)

Thanks,

Comment: (+1) However, it's always nice to **show** what you have done rather than saying, "I tried.. and it dint work". It gives a starting point (to find where the problem is and just work around it) and also the impression that you tried something.

Comment: Hello Arun, actually there are many ways to do this. I did not want to specify 1 way I am thinking of. Now i have 2 different ways to get the plots :) Thanks for your comment

Comment: In spite of that, you'd get quite a few variants! :) (if you check some other posts here on SO, you'll get the idea. good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try to post your data in an easy to copy-and-paste format, like I've done below:

```
mydata <- structure(list(col1 = c(84L, 94L, 188L, 245L, 114L, 71L, 118L, 
162L, 123L, 115L, 125L, 119L, 106L, 146L), col2 = c(88.242, 107.571, 
240.288, 371.005, 131.599, 100.751, 138.543, 203.435, 152.032, 
126.945, 134.178, 138.926, 129.19, 162.319), col3 = c(9.833, 
10.917, 16.917, 22.333, 9.167, 8.167, 11.167, 14.667, 12.167, 
11.667, 10, 9.5, 9.833, 9.833), col4 = c(4.194, 3.708, 6.333, 
10.389, 4.25, 3, 4.278, 6.444, 4.639, 5.056, 4.639, 4.222, 3.833, 
4.118), cr = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("col1", 
"col2", "col3", "col4", "cr"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Now. to address your question. You need to first `aggregate` the data, then convert it to a `matrix`, then calculate each value in the matrix as a proportion to the total in that column (using `prop.table`):

```
mydataAgg <- aggregate(cbind(col1, col2, col3, col4) ~ cr, mydata, sum)
mydata2 <- as.matrix(mydata1[-1])
rownames(mydata2) <- mydataAgg[[1]]
mydata2
#   col1     col2    col3   col4
# A 1235 1527.057 110.250 46.673
# B  575  697.967  55.918 22.430
prop.table(mydata2, 2)
#        col1      col2      col3      col4
# A 0.6823204 0.6863103 0.6634851 0.6754121
# B 0.3176796 0.3136897 0.3365149 0.3245879
```

Plotting is then easy:

```
barplot(prop.table(mydata2, 2))
```

Or, with colors:

```
barplot(prop.table(mydata2, 2), col = c("slateblue", "palevioletred"))
```

[image]

Hmmm. Not the most interesting plot, but I guess definitely a clear pattern in proportions....

---

### `lattice`

@Arun showed the `ggplot2` solution in the name of completeness, but if that's the case, then we should at least add `barchart` from "lattice". ;)

For this, we need to transpose the output of `prop.table(mydata2, 2)` that we calculated earlier:

```
barchart(t(prop.table(mydata2, 2)), stack = TRUE, horizontal = FALSE)
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: (+1) especially for the reaction after looking at the plot. `Hmmm.. not the most interesting plot..` :)

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness, here's the ggplot2 solution (using @AnandaMahto's data, thank you for the `dput` output). I use `melt` first and then use `data.table` to count and obtain proportions (all internal calculations basically):

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
require(data.table)

df.m <- melt(df, names(df)[5], names(df)[1:4])
dt <- data.table(df.m)
setkey(dt, "cr", "variable")
dt.m <- dt[, list(count = sum(value)), by=list(cr,variable)]
dt.m <- dt.m[, list(cr=cr, prop = count/sum(count)), by=variable]
p <- ggplot(data = dt.m, aes(factor(variable))) + 
         geom_bar(aes(group = cr, weights=prop, fill=cr))
p <- p + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
p
```

[image: ggplot2_barplot_stacked]

Comment: ggplot2 is simply a better way to do graphs. I'm of the view that the built-in plotting functions should always be ignored in favour of it.

Comment: Even though, sometimes you don't want to follow the grammar of graphics, where base plotting comes in handy...

Comment: Granted. Imagine appending "unless there's a good reason" to the end of my last comment.

Comment: +1 for completeness, but you forgot to add `lattice`, so I've updated my answer.